# Many to many join with filter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables like so -

Table 1 -

```
patient   admit_dt     discharge_dt
323       2020-01-09   2020-02-01
323       2020-02-18   2020-02-27
231       2020-02-13   2020-02-17
```

Table 2 -

```
patient   admit_dt     discharge_dt
323       2020-02-05   2020-02-07
231       2020-02-23   2020-02-28
```

The output I am needing is

```
patient   
323
```

The logic is - if one patient goes from `table 1` into `table 2` and ends up back in `table 1` within 30 days, we want to count them in the output.

`Patient 231` is not included in the result because they didn't go back to `table 1`.

Comment: Is the admit date of t2 always greater than the discharge date of t1 or can they be the same? What's your definition of 30 days - between the two t1 admit dates, betwwen the t2 discharge date and the 2nd t1 admit date, or something else?

Comment: Why does a patient go from one table to another table? To me this sounds like a different status, treatment, or whatever, but no reason to jump from one to another table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `join`:

```
select t1.patient
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.patient = t1.patient and
        t2.admit_dt > t1.discharge_dt join
     table1 tt1
     on tt1.patient = t1.patient and
        tt1.admit_dt > t2.discharge_dt;
```